# Mysql Collation for arabic using php

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I am facing problem with mysql database. I cant save arabic text into the mysql data even i change the collation to cp1256_general_ci and tried other collation. I cant get much help from search.

Anyone who can help me out please help

I have change collation at database level as well as colum level to cp1256_general_ci for some fields.

Please suggestion how should i set this as i am NEW PHP and MySQL

I also write simple INSERT statement to insert input data in mysql do i have to take any case while inserting data into mysql if it is in arabic

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433293/how-can-i-insert-arabic-word-to-mysql-database-using-java, it may help you.

Comment: it is related to Java i have to work in PHP

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: Use UTF-8 everywhere. "Everywhere" means

- In all forms that are used to store data in your database
- The database connection
- The database tables and columns
- In all pages that output data from the database.

if you have existing CP-1256 data (or incoming data in that character set that you can't change) you can use [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/iconv) to convert it into UTF-8.

Note that if using UTF-8, you need to make sure you use [multibyte-safe string functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661832/php-multibyte-string-functions) This is often already the case because standard function like `strlen()` get mapped to `mb_strlen()`. To find out whether this is the case on your server, [see the manual entry on the issue.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php)